# How to call a function on blur event for a tiny mce

Tags: tinymce

I want to write function that saves the content of tiny mce and destroys the current instance of tiny mce which will be called when the mce looses focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
// Code to be inserted into the init function of a plugin
ed.onDeactivate.add(function(ed) {
    ed.save();  // or whatever you want to do to save the editor content
    ed.remove(); // removes tinymce instance
});
```